# Devise sign_up from different view fails to save/create user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I try to allow users to enter an email and password directly from my home/landing page. For this I followed exactly this example:

http://pupeno.com/2010/08/29/show-a-devise-log-in-form-in-another-page/

So i placed the form in my index.html.erb and create a welcome_helper.rb like said in the article because my welcome controller controlls the index view homepage.

But what happens is that the user is not created / saved instead after hitting sign up I see this in the console:

```
Started GET "/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=mM52EgyczA4XgutnP37Q3rumj3HuHx8nYNRz5pas6lM%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=alex%2Bneun%40rivalfox.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&user%5Bremember_me%5D=0&commit=Sign+in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-21 14:24:21 +0100
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mM52EgyczA4XgutnP37Q3rumj3HuHx8nYNRz5pas6lM=", "user"=>{"email"=>"email@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 6.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

It seems that it is make a GET request, but I don't get why because the path is 100% the same as used on the normal Devise Sign Up page.

Any thoughts how I can solve the problem. In the article I posted there is someone else asked for the same question, but no answer. Couldn't find anything on the net either.

My index.html.erb looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 form-container">


<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do   
|f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

<div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us the code from your view.  It seems like your form submit button isn't a submit button, but a link.  Cannot be sure without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi I added the relevant part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `:url => registration_path(resource_name)` is not actually pointing to your create action.

This may not be the prettiest solution, but try replacing the first part of your form with this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => url_for(:controller => 'resource_controller', :action => 'create_action'), :method => :post) do |f| %>
```

Making sure you fill in the correct controller and action name.

If this works, you know it was an issue with your url, you could then troubleshoot your existing :url selection to see what the appropriate url would be (or leave the solution as noted above).

Comment: Tried it, modified the controller and action like this:    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => url_for(:controller => 'devise/registrations', :action => 'create')) do |f| %> Gives me no error, but still the same behavior.

Comment: Hmm, you could try to add the post type to the form, `:method => :post`.  I updated the code above to include it.  Let's see what that does.